# Row operations with UDF

Tags: pyspark, typeerror

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField, IntegerType

# Define the schema for the input DataFrame
input_schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True)
])

# Define the UDF that accepts an entire row as input and performs operations using columns
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def my_udf(row):
    col1 = row.col1
    col2 = row.col2
    result = col1 + col2
    return str(result)

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=input_schema)

# Apply the UDF to the DataFrame
result_df = df.withColumn("result", my_udf(df))
```

I am trying to run the above code, but I am seeing the below error:
`TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[col1: int, col2: int] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.`

spark version: `3.3.1` in databricks

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have tried multiple permutations and combinations on this, but I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a [struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html) of all of the columns:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

result_df = df.withColumn("result", my_udf(struct([df[col] for col in df.columns])))

+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|result|
+----+----+------+
|   1|   2|     3|
|   3|   4|     7|
|   5|   6|    11|
+----+----+------+
```